# synchronous Reset doesnt work (VHDL) in Simulation, but why?

Tags: vhdl, reset

I am really confused, because it is a simple code and I dont find the error. Syntax is fine, but in Simulation the Values of Dready and acc_value dont change.

This is my module MVM.vhd:

```
entity MVM is
  port (
    CLK:        IN  std_logic;
    RST:        IN  std_logic;
    DREADY:     OUT std_logic
  );
end entity MVM;

architecture base of MVM is
begin
  process(CLK)
  variable acc_value : signed(15 downto 0);
  begin
   IF rising_edge(CLK) then   
      IF RST='1' THEN
        acc_value := (OTHERS => '0'); -- reset 
        DREADY <= '0';
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END process;
end base;
```

If Reset is high, it should set the values of Dready and acc_value to "0"

My Testbench:

```
entity tb_MVM is
--  Port ( );
end tb_MVM;

architecture TEST of tb_MVM is

  Component MVM
  port (
    CLK:        IN  std_logic;
    RST:        IN  std_logic;
    DREADY:     OUT std_logic
  );
    End component;
    
    signal CLK:        std_logic;
    signal RST:        std_logic;
    signal DREADY:     std_logic;

    BEGIN
          uut:  MVM Port Map(
                CLK=>CLK,
                RST=>RST,
                DREADY => DREADY
                );
           
        tb: process    
        BEGIN
            wait for 100ns;
            CLK <= '1';
            RST <= '1';
            wait for 100ns;
            CLK <= '0';
            wait for 100ns;
            CLK <= '1';
            RST <= '0';
        END PROCESS;   
end TEST;
```

In the Simulation, the DREADY and  acc_value are undefined ('X')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the output *before* 300ns...

In simplified words: `rising_edge()` checks a transition from `'0'` to  `'1'`, and is not true for transitions from `'X'` to  `'1'`.

You might also want to make sure that `RST` is stable when `CLK` actually rises, for example:

```vhdl
        tb: process    
        BEGIN
            CLK <= '0';
            RST <= '1';
            wait for 100ns;
            CLK <= '1';
            wait for 100ns;
            CLK <= '0';
            RST <= '0';
        END PROCESS;
```

This brings `DREADY` and `acc_value` to zero after 100ns.

Comment: We call those typographical errors or colloquially think-o's where you meant one thing and wrote another.

Comment: You are right, it should set it to "0" and not to "1".
Anyhow, in simulation but it is neither 0 or 1, its "x" (undefined/unknown)